# Why does psql treat statements after COPY as stdin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Example script:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo(col1 text);
COPY foo from STDIN DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;

SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Execution:

```
psql --host=localhost --dbname=postgres --username=postgres \
  --file=my-script.sql < my-data.tsv
```

When I run this, something peculiar happens. `SELECT * FROM foo` doesn't run, and instead everything below the `COPY` statement is treated as rows to be entered into my table.

How can I write a SQL script that imports a data table from standard input and does further processing with it?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

psql treats `--file` scripts as if they were standard input, so it's expecting your data set to immediately follow the `COPY` statement. There is a workaround, as per [this email](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20101113150402.67e3ddfe%40dick.coachhouse) on the Postgres mailing list:

```
cat my-data.tsv | psql -c "$(cat my-script.sql)"
```